# Unexpected result of Tesseract while using 'digits' flag

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tess4j

My image is [image: target image] and when I do

```
tesseract myimage.png result digits
```

I am getting result as **80 1 3047490** though I am expecting to get only digit, that is **4749** in my image. What I am doing wrong ? My Tesseract version is 3.03.

PS: I also tried with no success `tesseract myimage.png result nobatch digits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected result: the output is forced to be all digits. In this case, I would use Regex to extract the digits from the mixed output, or substring if you know the position of the numbers in the string.

Comment: Thanks @nguyenq for input but I can't use Regex as Tesseract sometimes read letter 'S' as '9'(and vice-versa). I wanted Tesseract to do character matching only against digit if possible.

Comment: You might want to try the [bazaar](https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html) pattern: `\A\A\A\A\A\d\d\d\d\A`

Comment: Hii @nguyenq , I tried to use bazaar pattern but couldn't succeed as there is almost no documentation with example. Can you guide me what commands you use for bazaar pattern?